# Не могу получить высоты и ширину родительского элемента с помощью jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

У меня есть документ:

```
    <div class = "room">
       <div class = "network">
          <div class = "head button">Сеть</div>
          <div class = "tail button my_btn">+</div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

При клике на div с классом my_btn мне нужно получить размеры родительского элемента div с классом network.

Код jQuery

```
$(".network").children(".my_btn").click( ListExpand );
function ListExpand( event ) {
    var target = $(event.target)
    var X = Math.floor(target.closest(".network").css("height"));
    var Y = Math.floor(target.closest(".network").css("width"));
}
```

Проверяю значения из консоли, а там NaN и NaN соответственно. Подскажите, где ошибка или предложите свой вариант.

CSS:

```
.network{
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}


.room{
    background-color: #985f0d;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 3px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.head{
    height: 40px;
    width: 100px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: inherit;
    float:left;
}


.tail{
    height: 40px;
    width: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 40px;
    border-top-right-radius: 40px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: inherit;
    float: left;
}


.button {
    color: #fff; /* цвет текста */
    text-decoration: none; /* убирать подчёркивание у ссылок */
    user-select: none; /* убирать выделение текста */
    background: rgb(212,75,56); /* фон кнопки */
    padding: .7em 1.5em; /* отступ от текста */
    outline: none; /* убирать контур в Mozilla */
} 

.button:hover { background: rgb(232,95,76); } /* при наведении курсора мышки */
.button:active { background: rgb(152,15,0); } /* при нажатии */

.prokrutka {
    position: absolute;
    display:none;
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    height:150px; /* высота нашего блока */
    background: #fff; /* цвет фона, белый */
    border: 1px solid #C1C1C1; /* размер и цвет границы блока */
    overflow-x: scroll; /* прокрутка по горизонтали */
    overflow-y: scroll; /* прокрутка по вертикали */
}
```

Comment: `target.closest(".network").height()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в стиле дочерние элементы указаны с `float`, а он делает элементы "невидимыми" для родителя, по этому высота была 0, а если не указать ширину `display:block`, то она будет равняться ширине окна или родительского элемента. Нужно для `.network` тоже указать float, или сделать фиксированную высоту

```js
function ListExpand( event ) {
    var target = $(event.target)
    var X = Math.floor(target.closest(".network").height());
    var Y = Math.floor(target.closest(".network").width());
    console.log(X);
    console.log(Y);
};
$(function() {
  $(".network").children(".my_btn").click( ListExpand );
});
```

```css
.network{
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}


.room{
    background-color: #985f0d;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 3px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.head{
    height: 40px;
    width: 100px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: inherit;
    float:left;
}


.tail{
    height: 40px;
    width: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 40px;
    border-top-right-radius: 40px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: inherit;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "network">
  <div class = "head button">Сеть</div>
  <div class = "tail button my_btn">+</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Попробовал, результат получился неоднозначный: X = 0 и Y = 1567. Очень странно, ведь "на глаз" родительский элемент имеет значение ~100x50

Comment: @ЕвгенийВасильев, а так?

Comment: Нет, результат тот же.

Comment: @ЕвгенийВасильев, а загрузите CSS этих элементов в вопрос. Что-то странно у вас там или киньте ссылку на jsfiddle )

Comment: @ЕвгенийВасильев, у вас в стилях была проблема, ну и в jquery тоже

Comment: Спасибо, теперь результаты корректные.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте элементам напрямую, через this и parent:

```
     <div class = "room">
       <div class = "network">
          <div class = "head button">Сеть</div>
          <div class = "tail button my_btn" style="cursor: pointer;">+</div>
       </div>
   </div>

    <script>

    $(".my_btn").click(function ListExpand(){
        var x = Math.floor($(this).parent().height());
        var y = Math.floor($(this).parent().width());
        console.log(x + "; " + y);
    })
    </script>
```